# Adding Views into a Mutable Array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I would like to know if i can put a view into a NSMutableArray, working with UIPageControl and ScrollView.

Comment: Is your question how to use `UIScrollView`s with `UIPageControl`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `UIView` into a `NSMutableArray` by just calling `addObject`, but that won't achieve very much, what you're probably trying to do is to display a bunch of `UIView` into a `UIScrollView` with pagination enabled, and a `UIPageControl`, a process which is described [here](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

Comment: Hey! I believe i've found another alternative for this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is **Yes**.
You can add any type of object to `NSMutableArray`.

```
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject:tempView];
[tempView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any sort of Objects to your Array/ Dictionary. Basically all the views are objects. So you can simply add it like any other object. eg. [myArray addObject:myViewObject]. But Inorder to add objects dynamically you must define the Array/ Dictionary as Mutable. (ie, `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableDictionary`)